# Can not download .apk file from asp.net web api in https

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My  `Web API` code as below,working in http mode  but do not work in https mode .No error show,just give me a http 204 state code,can not download apk file anyway,my server is windows 2012.Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DownloadFileFromWebApi.Controllers
{
  [RoutePrefix("download")]
  public class DownloadController : ApiController
  {
    [Route("get_demo_file")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFileFromWebApi()
    {
      try
      {
        var FilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/download/app.apk");
        var stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { 
        FileName="app.apk"
        };
        return response;
      }
      catch
      {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
      }
    }
  }
}
```